# Make an Eclipse Plugin as an Extension Point for UML Designer Obeo

Tags: uml-designer

How can I extend the functionality of the UML designer?
I want to be able to load some specific class file and show the infos(attributes, relations) into the UML Diagram?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As UML Designer is based on [Eclipse Sirius](http://eclipse.org/sirius), you need to update the diagrams specification : [uml2.odesign](https://github.com/ObeoNetwork/UML-Designer/blob/master/plugins/org.obeonetwork.dsl.uml2.design/description/uml2.odesign).
If you don't know yet Sirius, you can have a look to the [get started](https://www.eclipse.org/sirius/getstarted.html) page.

If you have more specific questions do not hesitate!

Comment: Thank you for your answer! but I want  to create my own plugin as an extension point to the uml designer plugin.Something like this : <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?eclipse version="3.4"?>
<plugin>
   <extension
         point="org.eclipse.ui.popupMenus"> .... is it possible to have the path to the uml designer there ?

Comment: Could you precise your question ? You want to add menus on what?

Comment: So, **first option** would be to develop my own  plugin based on the UML designer in order to extend the functionalities or  **second option** would be to download the source code from github and try to modify that according to my requirements? My question was if i will choose the 1 option how it will look the extension point for this ?Thank you!